# Get date quantiles in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have some data that looks something like:

```
user  timestamp  value1 
   a 2007-01-01       7 
   a 2007-02-02       8 
   a 2007-02-03       9 
   b 2007-02-04       1 
   a 2007-02-05       2 
   b 2007-02-06       3 
   b 2007-02-07       4 
   a 2007-02-08       5 
...
```

where each user has a different number of entries.

My goal is to have a sense of how quickly these entries are being produced, and output something like:

```
     last_entry median_entry first_entry
user                                    
a    2007-02-08   2007-02-03  2007-01-01
b    2007-02-07   2007-02-06  2007-02-04
```

So far, I have code like:

```
gb = df.groupby('user')
time_median = gb['timestamp'].median()
```

But this gives me `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`, presumably because dates are not numeric.

I guess it would be possible to turn the dates into timestamps, and find the median of those, and then turn them back into date_time objects. Is that the best way?

Comment: For the quantiles, it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: Ah yes disregard that, removed since it was irrelevant. Unsure what I was thinking

Answer (score 2):

I may have been unclear in my question, but I found a solution that works for me.

```
def get_quantile(df, q):
    # Function that gets quantile from integer timestamp, then changes
    # back to a date_time object
    return pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].quantile(q, interpolation='nearest'))

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user': np.random.choice(['a', 'b','c'], size=100, replace=True), 'value': np.random.random(size=100), 'date_time': pd.date_range(start=date(2016, 1,1), freq='D', periods=100)})

# Make a column of integer timestamps
df['timestamp'] = df['date_time'].astype('int')

editors = d.groupby('editor')

result = pd.DataFrame()
# Add columns of quantiles
result['first_quantile'] = get_quantile(editors, .25)
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.searchsorted()` for the number of days half way between the `max` and the `min` for each user:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user': np.random.choice(['a', 'b','c'], size=100, replace=True), 'value': np.random.random(size=100), 'time_stamp': pd.date_range(start=date(2016, 1,1), freq='D', periods=100)})

df.groupby('user')['time_stamp'].describe()

user        
a     count                      28
      unique                     28
      top       2016-02-03 00:00:00
      freq                        1
      first     2016-01-01 00:00:00
      last      2016-04-05 00:00:00
b     count                      38
      unique                     38
      top       2016-03-24 00:00:00
      freq                        1
      first     2016-01-02 00:00:00
      last      2016-04-08 00:00:00
c     count                      34
      unique                     34
      top       2016-01-28 00:00:00
      freq                        1
      first     2016-01-03 00:00:00
      last      2016-04-09 00:00:00
```

For median:

```
df.groupby('user')['time_stamp'].apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().iloc[x.searchsorted(x.min() + (x.max()-x.min())/2)])

dtype: object
user    
a     54   2016-02-24
b     50   2016-02-20
c     51   2016-02-21
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to treat each date after the initial date for each user as the number of days since this initial date, you could do something like

```
import pandas as pd
dts =  pd.date_range(start="2015-01-15", periods=20)
users = ["a","b"]*10
df = pd.DataFrame({"user":users, "timestamp":dts})

date_info = df.groupby("user").agg({"timestamp":[min, max]})
date_info.columns = date_info.columns.droplevel()

since_incept = lambda x: x - x.min()
df["days"] = df.groupby("user").transform(since_incept)
df["days"] = df["days"].dt.days

median_td = lambda x: pd.Timedelta(pd.Series.median(x), "D")
med = df.groupby("user").agg({"days":[median_td]})

date_info["median"] = date_info["min"] + med.loc[:, ("days", "<lambda>")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you can try using `pd.TimeGrouper` and change the frequency (`'20D'`, `'M'`, etc) to fit your time horizon. Here is an example using 5-quantiles (100 days, 20 day groups):

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': np.random.choice(['a', 'b','c'], size=100, replace=True),
                   'value': np.random.randint(10, size=100),
                   'time_stamp': pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(2016, 1,1), freq='D', periods=100)})
df.head()

  time_stamp user  value
0 2016-01-01    b      3
1 2016-01-02    c      4
2 2016-01-03    a      8
3 2016-01-04    b      5
4 2016-01-05    c      5
```

Quantile generation:

```
quantiles = df.set_index('time_stamp').groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='20D'), 'user'])['value'].sum()

time_stamp  user
2016-01-01  a       48
            b       22
            c       29
2016-01-21  a       28
            b       26
            c       25
2016-02-10  a       20
            b       57
            c       26
2016-03-01  a       25
            b       37
            c       35
2016-03-21  a       15
            b       37
            c       22
```

For a cumulative view:

```
cum_quantiles = quantiles.groupby(level=[1]).cumsum()

time_stamp  user
2016-01-01  a        48
            b        22
            c        29
2016-01-21  a        76
            b        48
            c        54
2016-02-10  a        96
            b       105
            c        80
2016-03-01  a       121
            b       142
            c       115
2016-03-21  a       136
            b       179
            c       137
```

If you want to see values in percentage terms, try adding a percentage column:

```
totals = df.groupby('user')['value'].sum()
df['pct'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['value']/float(totals[x['user']]), axis=1)
```

And repeat the above steps changing `'value'` to `'pct'`

Answer (score 1):

### Grouping with our own median function

#### Set up your columns

```
df['first_entry'] = df['timestamp']
df['median_entry'] = df['timestamp']
df['last_entry'] = df['timestamp']
```

#### Define our own median function for time

```
def median_time(x):
    x = list(x)
    median_entry = (len(x) - 1) / 2.0
    x.sort()
    if median_entry % 1 == 0:
        return x[int(median_entry)]
    else:
        lower_date = x[int(median_entry)]
        upper_date = x[int(median_entry) + 1]
        return lower_date + (upper_date - lower_date) / 2.0
```

#### Set up the aggregation configuration

```
agg_config = {'first_entry': pd.np.min,
              'median_entry': median_time,
              'last_entry': pd.np.max}
```

#### Aggregate

```
df.groupby('user').agg(agg_config)
```

#### Result

```
     last_entry median_entry first_entry
user                                    
a    2007-02-08   2007-02-03  2007-01-01
b    2007-02-07   2007-02-06  2007-02-04
```

### Alternative, Simpler median

You can also do a faulty median this way if you want whole dates only:

```
def median_time(x):
    x = list(x)
    median_entry = (len(x) - 1) / 2.0
    x.sort()
    return x[round(median_entry)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an exact median, you can sort the dates and take the approximate middle (e.g. median of an even number of elements would be the first number in the tuple pair, so median of `1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6` would be 2 because (2, 4) are the middle elements).

```
>>> df.groupby('user').timestamp.agg({
        'first_entry': 'first', 
        'last_entry': 'last', 
        'median_entry': lambda group: sorted(group)[len(group) // 2]})

      last_entry first_entry median_entry
user                                     
a     2007-02-08  2007-01-01   2007-02-03
b     2007-02-07  2007-02-04   2007-02-06
```